# Firefox- How to change font size of items in bookmarks sidebar

Tags: firefox, fonts, bookmarks, sidebar

In Windows. (I know I can open `Desktop > Properties > Appearance > Advanced` > [and figure out which item determines it; probably `Menu`]. But, I don't want other things changed - just the bookmarks. This is because I have so many and I want more of them to display.

I did see the question on changing font size of items in folder, on bookmarks toolbar, and sub-folders, etc; But, I'm talking sidebar on **firefox**, I don't have Google Chrome and I am not a developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector for the items in the Bookmarks Sidebar is `#bookmarks-view`. So, for example, adding the following rule in your [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) will change the font size to `20px`:

```
#bookmarks-view
{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Thank you! 
Stupid follow-up qus: must I install Chrome to do that? (But Chromoe is part of Google, not part of FF, right?) Does Chrome grab my private info?

Comment: This has nothing to do with **Google Chrome**. Follow the `userChrome.css` link in my answer for directions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an add-on for Firefox: [Theme Font & Size Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/theme-font-size-changer/)

> Theme Font & Size Changer lets you change the global font size and font family used for the user interface in Firefox. Design your browser with your favorite font.